# python matrix search

Tags: python, matrix, find, element

If I have the following matrix:

```
import numpy

ar = numpy.array((('0','1','2','3'), ('1','a','b','b'), ('2','b','c','d')), str)
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[['0' '1' '2' '3']
 ['1' 'a' 'b' 'b']
 ['2' 'b' 'c' 'd']]
```

And I want to get the value where the condition for row and column is met. The header row are the columns (could be strings) and the first column on the left are all rows (could be strings). So if I have '2' for column and '2' for row I would get 'c'. I don't know 'c' yet only the values for rows and columns. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
In [7]: numpy.where(ar == 'c')
Out[7]: (array([2]), array([2]))
```

and:

```
In [8]: ar[numpy.where(ar == 'c')]
Out[8]: 
array(['c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean searching for 'c':

```
numpy.where(ar == 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ar = [['0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['1', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
 ['2', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

print(ar[2][2])
```

The above is just for accessing the 'c' in column 2, row 2, if you want to access a whole column you would have to:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    print(ar[2][i])
```

Comment: Hi, I think this is going in the right direction but is this also working when I have all string values in the matrix like ar = numpy.array((('fc','sc','tc','fc'), ('fr','a','b','b'), ('sr','b','c','d')), str). Maybe I should have asked differently. I have the value for the column and the value for the row. Both are strings. I don't know 'c' yet. I have to look it up in the matrix with the values for colum and row like coordinates.